# Laravel дублируются данные

Tags: laravel, insert, action

Есть action который находится под стандартным auth middleware. Этот action вставляет в базу 20 записей. Так вот если разлогиниться, аутентифицироваться вновь и вызвать этот action - вставка данных дублируется, т.е. вставляется 40 записей. Причем, если просмотреть коллекцию методом dd() - записей в коллекции ровно 20. Сетую на то, что метод при первом его вызове после аутентификации - вызывается дважды. Кто-то сталкивался с подобным поведением?

Потестил, действительно, экшен вызывается 2 раза, но только после первого после аутентификации вызова этого экшена. Повторные вызовы не дублируются. WTF?

UPD: изменил роут с `Route::('backpack/update', ...);` на `Route::('backpack/upd', ...);`, стало работать нормально. Как то нездорово реагирует на слово `update` в роуте, причина до сих пор не ясна.

Comment: Без демонстрации проблемного кода, вам врятли кто то поможет

Comment: Проблема решена, она была не в коде. Функция браузера Chrome "Использовать подсказки для ускорения загрузки страниц" отправляла запрос ещё при вводе ULR а адресную строку, при авто-заполнении, а после того как я нажимал `Enter` - отправлялся второй запрос.